# incremental backup in every 10 minutes in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I used pg_dump command to dump the database using command:

```
pg_dump -Fc -v -f full_dump.sql -U admin new_db
```

and it dumps database but how to incremental backup database every 10 min

but data retention should be in every 90 days. I am using postgresql 15. Backup should be done from pgadmin 4 database.

How do I solve this issue in ubuntu?

I wrote script.sh and ensured that the script has executable permissions:

```
 chmod +x script.sh
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

DATABASE_NAME="host=localhost port=5432 dbname=new_db user=admin password=admin"
BACKUP_DIR="/home/ubuntu/Documents"
DATE=$(date +"2023-06-30_11-11-11")
BACKUP_FILE="$BACKUP_DIR/backup_$DATE.tar"

sudo -u admin pg_dump -Fc $DATABASE_NAME > $BACKUP_FILE
```

and execute command crontab -e to execute in every 10 minutes and it backups the database in defined location but the size is 0 byte.

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but why don't you use Continuous Archiving? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html

Comment: Check this extension [pgbackrest](https://pgbackrest.org/user-guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are far better off thinking about this in terms of Point in Time Recovery than trying to do incremental backups every 10 minutes.  There are a few tools for this such as Barman and Pgbackrest.

The problem is that incremental backups have to somehow identify changes and this is not likely to be very helpful.  But WAL itself is something like an incremental backup.

So my recommendation is to look at Pgbackrest and Barman and see PITR as your primary approach for incremental backups.

Pgbackrest has incremental backup options but those are not intended to be used every ten minutes.